# How to change css read more button

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to change read more button style by adding hover.
I tried some CSS like:

```
a:hover{
  background-color: #077fad;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

or

```
div.blmore.rmbutton-center.rmbutton-medium:hover{
  background-color: #077fad;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

But the first approach changes also `<a>` inside the `<h2>` paragraph and the other one adds hover to the whole read more button section, except the read more button.

My question is how to select the `<a>` inside `<div class="blmore rmbutton-center rmbutton-medium">` paragraph and how to apply hover effect only to that section?

```
<div id="bloglist_title">
    <h2 class="entry-title">
    <a href="my.website.link.com">Title</a>
    </h2>
</div>
<div class="entry-content">
    <div class="myleft">
    <a class="entry-post-thumbnail left" style etc.....></a>
<p>
Short text
</p>
<div id="bloglist_morebutton">
    <div class="blmore rmbutton-center rmbutton-medium">
        <a style="background-color: #fdc550; border-radius: 5px;"href="my.website.link.com">Read more</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/* gets applied to any hovered <a> on the page */
.a:hover {}

/* gets applied to an hovered <a> on the page
   within the given class combination */
.blmore.rmbutton-center.rmbutton-medium a:hover {}

/* gets applied to any <a> within an hovered
   element of the given class combination */
.blmore.rmbutton-center.rmbutton-medium:hover a {}
```

The key is the whitespace between two classes or elements, which allows you to represent the nesting of the markup.

Comment: Thanks @Marvin. I tried all options but nither works (no changes at all). Is it possible that read more button section has no hover effect by deafult and that is why formula can not be appied to it?

Comment: Could it be that your inline styles (the CSS inside the `style` attribute of your `a`) override the styles you want to apply to your a on hover? See this fiddle to understand what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/sucjazt6/

Comment: Yes it is correct! I have inspected my page an that is exactly what is happening.

Comment: Then you either need to remove the inline styles or, if not possible, add ` !important` to the specific properties. [See the updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sucjazt6/2/)